# CSS adjacent sibling selectors, Safari and <nav> elements

Tags: css, html, safari, css-selectors

In Safari 5.1.3 I have just noticed that, when writing a CSS adjacent sibling selector (er the `+` one) and when referencing a `<nav>` element - the browser fails to honor the CSS.

So:

```
h1 + p { ... } /* works fine */
h1+p { ... } /* works fine */
```

and

```
h1 + nav { ... } /* works fine */
h1+nav { ... } /* but, does NOT work */
```

I've tested these with other html 5 elements (section, article, aside) and they seem to work fine. Until you put a nav element into the mix; then it breaks. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rdeM/3/).

This is proving frustrating as my rails asset packer is minifying the css and taking out unnecessary spaces. This isn't an issue for IE7, Firefox, Chrome or Opera - but Safari 5..

Anyone else had similar? Know why? Know a way to fix?

Comment: file a bug report with safari

Comment: I'm receiving the same bug on Safari. I have also noticed that `h1+ nav` works. The only time it stops working is when `+` touches `nav`.

Comment: Reproduced on Safari 5.1.3 on Mac OS X 10.7.3.

Answer (score 6):

This is definitely a Safari bug and you should report it using **Safari > Report Bugs to Apple...** on a Mac or **Help > Report Bugs to Apple...** on a PC (or the toolbar button if it's displayed on your Safari toolbar).

The easiest way out of this is to disable CSS minification if Asset Packager has an option for it.

If it doesn't have such an option, there exists a quick and dirty workaround: if you only have one `nav` element directly following your `h1`, you can use the [general sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) instead as Safari doesn't appear to have any problems with it:

```
h1 ~ nav { ... } /* works fine */
h1~nav { ... } /* works fine */
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/4rdeM/4)

If you have multiple `nav` elements following your `h1`, you'll have to override the styles manually for the successive `nav` elements using `h1 ~ nav ~ nav`.

Comment: It's fortunate that I can suggest the use of `~` under only the assumption that, since you mentioned that it's not an issue in IE7, you're only developing for IE7 and later, which supports both `+` and `~` (you're probably not testing in IE6 because it doesn't support either combinator anyway).