# Why does the general-sibling combinator allow toggling pseudo-element's content, but not the adjacent-sibling?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In this question "[CSS3 Selector That Works like jQuery's .click()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17217585/)" I [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17217826/82548) using the `:checked` state of an `input`, of `type="checkbox"` to toggle the display of an element.

This is the HTML of the demo I posted in that answer:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" />
<nav>
    <h2>This would be the 'navigation' element.</h2>
</nav>
<label for="switch">Toggle navigation</label>
```

And the CSS (with transitions stripped for brevity):

```
#switch {
    display: none;
}
#switch + nav {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* transitions followed */
}
#switch:checked + nav {
    height: 4em;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #ffa;
    /* transitions followed */
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rUkRS/1/).

Once I'd posted the answer it occurred to me that we could *also* toggle the text of the `label` used to trigger the state-change of that checkbox, using the following selectors (having amended the `label`'s text to 'navigation'):

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#switch + nav + label::before {
    content: 'Show ';
}

#switch:checked + nav + label::before {
    content: 'Hide ';
}
```

[Simplified/basic JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rUkRS/6/).

This did not work, in that while the selector matched while the `input` was in its unchecked state (and the `label` showed `Show navigation`), the selector *failed* to match when the state of the `input` changed. Note that the transitions were still effected on the `nav` element, and the original matching selector indicates that the next-sibling combinator matched originally. The above link shows a simplified demo of the not-working (in Chrome 27/Windows XP) selectors.

It then occurred to me to try the general-sibling combinator, to reduce the selector-chain. which resulted in the following CSS (with transitions again stripped for brevity):

```
#switch:checked + nav {
    background-color: #ffa;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#switch ~ label::before {
    content: 'Show ';
}

#switch:checked ~ label::before {
    content: 'Hide ';
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rUkRS/4/).

Somewhat to my surprise, this worked (the `content` of the `label` changed in response to the changed-state of the `input`).

So, the question: why does the general-sibling combinator allow for updating of a later-sibling while chained next-sibling combinators (which match the elements and the structure of the DOM) does not?

Further, this *does* seem to work in Firefox (21, on Windows XP); so I guess the question is altered slightly to include: is this a bug in Chrome/Webkit, or an expected behaviour?

And, even *further*, it seems that while this is a bug in Chrome (thanks @Boltclock), there's a somewhat ludicrous ['do-nothing' animation](http://css-tricks.com/webkit-sibling-bug/) that fixes the non-working demo (though other, perhaps better, alternatives exist, as Scott's answer shows):

```
body {
    -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bugfix {
    from {
        padding: 0;
    }
    to {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
#switch {
}
#switch + nav {
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
#switch:checked + nav {
    background-color: #ffa;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#switch + nav + label::before {
    content:'Show ';
}
#switch:checked + nav + label::before {
    content:'Hide ';
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rUkRS/14/).

**Note:** the reason I'm updating the question with this 'fix,' rather than posting it as an answer, is simply because the question *wasn't* "how can I fix this?" but (basically) "why doesn't it work?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a long-standing bug in WebKit browsers related to the use of certain dynamic pseudo-classes with next-sibling combinators. This happens whether you're applying styles to the sibling element itself or a pseudo-element of that sibling element.

I don't know if anybody has filed a bug report yet, but this has been seen rather frequently on the site:

- [Webkit bug with `:hover` and multiple adjacent-sibling selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320530/webkit-bug-with-hover-and-multiple-adjacent-sibling-selectors)
- [CSS adjacent sibling selectors, Safari and <nav> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318474/css-adjacent-sibling-selectors-safari-and-nav-elements)

Strangely it was also reported that Chrome had issues with the general sibling combinator, but as you note it works in your given scenario:

- [Why doesn't this CSS selector work: a:hover ~ span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061509/why-doesnt-this-css-selector-work-ahover-span)

So either that was fixed, or something else triggers/triggered it.

Comment: Ugh, I need to learn how to effectively-search for Webkit bugs.

Comment: Don't worry, they're hard to find on purpose. You'll just have to encounter them as you work.

Comment: Thanks! And, suddenly, I don't know whether to be happy that Opera's switching to Webkit (they might fix the bug) or wary (they might adopt new, and frustrating, old-bugs).

Comment: We're just going to have to trust the good people at Opera. Presto was an awesome engine that did many things way better than WebKit, so either they manage to patch things up, or we're basically hosed.

Comment: Which is the reason I was, even initially, wary of the change. While I didn't love Opera, as such, I *did* admire their rendering engine, and their implementation of standards. Oh, and *ludicrously*, using a '[do-nothing](http://css-tricks.com/webkit-sibling-bug/)' animation [fixes it](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rUkRS/14/).

Comment: You should know that I am extremely biased against WebKit and toward Trident and Gecko at this point :P I especially applaud Microsoft's strategy of focusing IE8 on CSS2.1 compliance — it really shows, and puts sketchy tech demos like Chrome in their place.

Answer (score 16):

### Bug Work Around

Apparently, *certain* valid pseudo-classes *chained together* allows it to work.

These work (see [Fiddle #1](http://jsfiddle.net/rUkRS/21/), [Fiddle #2](http://jsfiddle.net/rUkRS/22/), [Fiddle #3](http://jsfiddle.net/rUkRS/23/)):

```css
#switch:checked + nav:only-of-type + label::before
#switch:checked + nav:nth-of-type(1) + label::before
#switch:checked + nav:nth-child(2) + label::before
```

This did not (see [Fiddle #4](http://jsfiddle.net/rUkRS/24/)):

```css
#switch:checked + nav:not([class]) + label::before
```

I tried some other `:not()` combinations, none of which allowed it to work.

### ** **[Best choice](http://jsfiddle.net/rUkRS/25/)** **

```css
#switch:checked + nav:nth-child(n) + label::before
```

Comment: Does `:nth-child(n)` work? If so, that's the best bet, because it's a guaranteed match (well, technically equivalent to `:not(:root)`, but the root element is irrelevant here).

Comment: Your answer reminds me of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301357/safari-bug-first-child-doesnt-update-displayblock-when-items-are-removed-with/15302066#15302066).

Comment: YES! I was seeking a "guaranteed" match idea, and that does work!

Comment: @Scott: I'm up-voting because that really is quite awesome! But I'll leave the accepted answer as-is, because the work-around wasn't the question as such (for another work-around see the question itself, for example); but seriously: way to go! =)

Comment: Yes, I did not expect you to switch your accepted answer, as it is in fact a bug. But I did feel this would be useful for others.

Comment: @BoltClock: thanks. And David, I know you added the "do-nothing" animation fix to your question, but personally, I would minimize or eliminate that since I think this workaround is better than that one.

Comment: I tend to agree, but I had no intention that it should be *the* solution, it was just the option I found while searching for solutions to the problem (though I'll edit in a moment to add that it's merely *one* such solution).