# Use checkbox & javascript to hide/display ajax action links - MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

Does anyone know how I could use JavaScript with a checkbox in order to hide one ajax ActionLink and display another when the checkbox is checked?

View:

```
@Html.Label("Title")
@Html.CheckBox("CheckBox")

@Ajax.ActionLink("Do Stuff1", "SoStuff1", new { Id = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions{//ajaxoptions},

@Ajax.ActionLink("Do Stuff2", "SoStuff2", new { Id = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions{//ajaxoptions},
```

Thanks

Comment: If you show your HTML you might not need JavaScript.

Comment: I don't have it at hand, it's standard HTML view for a MVC4 app. What in the HTML could determine if I don't need to use JavaScript?

Comment: He is showing the HTML that is MVC for actionlinks using razer syntax

Comment: is it possible to assign different ID for the two action links? if it is, just do a regular jquery stuff. fx: $('#actionlinkid').hide() and $('#actionlinkid').show() on check box checked event.

Comment: @devC: the structure of the DOM, I don't know how that syntax typically renders, but if it's predictable then 'view source' should give the relevant output.

Comment: @DavidThomas: how in the world would the OP never not need JavaScript to show/hide something based on a checkbox. The mere description of the problem screams the need for JavaScript.

Comment: @Chris: HTML and CSS can definitely (within certain constraints) do this, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19755019/82548 and it's those constraints that make the rendered HTML necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ajax.ActionLink` has no overload that allows passing custom HTML attributes, and it's going to be hard to show/hide one or the other without being able to reference some id or class. You *could*, I suppose, wrap the link in a div or span, and then apply an id or class to *that*. That would actually probably be the safest and quickest course.

Once you have something you can select with, the JavaScript is trivial  (I should say "the jQuery", as I always hate it when other people equate the two. But, ASP.NET MVC uses jQuery by default, so support can be assumed.):

```
$('#CheckBox').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#link1').show();
        $('#link2').hide();
    } else {
        $('#link1').hide();
        $('#link2').show();
    }
});
```

FWIW, I would caution against the entire gamut of `Ajax` helpers. Automagic code is great, but automagic *AJAX* code, I believe, is a step too far. There's too much going on there and it's all hidden from the developer. That's a recipe for disaster.