# Safari 7.1 CSS Problems with sibling selector

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, css-selectors

Im using the Bootstrap plugin [awesome-bootstrap-ckeckbox](https://github.com/flatlogic/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox), Im working with ASP.NET MVC too, then all my checkbox render two inputs, one as a checkbox input and another as a hidden input, because of that I modified the CSS selector, for example:

HTML Code

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
   <input type="hidden" />
   <label for="checkbox1">
      Default
   </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
   <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" checked>
   <input type="hidden" />
   <label for="checkbox2">
       Primary
    </label>
 </div>
```

CSS Code

```
/* awesome-bootstrap-checkbox */
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f00c"; 
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label::before {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    cursor: not-allowed; 
}
.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background-color: #428bca;
    border-color: #428bca; 
}
.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    color: #fff; 
}

/* my own version */
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input + label::after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f00c"; 
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + input + label::before {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    cursor: not-allowed; 
}
.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input + label::before {
    background-color: #428bca;
    border-color: #428bca; 
}
.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input + label::after {
    color: #fff; 
}
```

That works great in all modern browser except Safari 7.1, incredibly the original works but my modification not, I think the problem is with the sibling selector. Any idea???

Plunker Code: [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/6MLHyX9n9tnNjOPWtcsP?p=preview)

Comment: @Clive check the Plunker link.

Comment: @Adrift I changed the selector and now is working, can you tell why???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug in Safari (unsure about Safari 8) and older versions of Chrome. There are several workarounds but the one I've used in practice is just replacing `+` with the `~` combinator:

```
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ input ~ label::after
```

Also here are other questions addressing the same bug:

- [Webkit bug with `:hover` and multiple adjacent-sibling selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320530/webkit-bug-with-hover-and-multiple-adjacent-sibling-selectors)
- [CSS adjacent sibling selectors, Safari and <nav> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318474/css-adjacent-sibling-selectors-safari-and-nav-elements)

Comment: that's nth-child. Removed comment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032513/ios8-safari-after-a-pushstate-the-nth-child-selectors-not-works